# performance issue in IE9 and not in IE8 on validating mandatory controls and date controls

Tags: javascript, validation, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Java Script validation Performance issue in IE9 and not in IE8 during validating the entry field and Data of birth field:

Behavior of System:

Overview about the system behavior, System has to validate all the mandatory entry field(6 controls), 
dropdown fields(5 controls) and Date Of Birth(1 control) field to validate date and some validation related to entry
field like only alphanumeric to key in and only specific Thai language character to key in with regular expression.

Once all the validation passes, system has to enable the next button to navigate next page in an Wizard.

Coding:

To accomplish the above functionality, coded in Java script when ever user key in a single character 
in any of the mandatory fields, system will check for all the fields are having valid data 
to enable next and clear the mandatory symbol(red * to indicate mandatory field).

```
attachEvent(ctrls, "onkeyup", handleValidation());

function handleValidation(){
var arrCtrls = getAllRequiredCtrls();

var blnvalidated = false;

for(i=0; attCtrls.length(); i++){
    objCtrls = arrCtrls[i];
    if(objCtrls.Validate == true){
        var objFunc = ObjCtrls._ValidateFunc;
        blnvalidated = eval(objFunc);
    if(blnvalidated) continue;
    else break;
}
    if(blnvalidated) enableButton(butNext);

}
```

Issue:

So, when key in any of the mandatory controls it takes quite a long time to validate all fields and allow the next char to key in.
**This performance issue occurs only in IE9 not in IE8.**

**Validating all mandatory fields is very much required to verify all fields having valid data to 
enable next button to navigate next page.**

Please suggest to resolve this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE9 comes with profiler... Did you tried to use it?

Comment: If this is really what you're doing `attachEvent(ctrls, "onkeyup", handleValidation());`, that is not correct.  You would be calling `handleValidation()` once and only once when the page is first loaded and not calling it in `onkeyup`.  Instead, you should be doing this: `attachEvent(ctrls, "onkeyup", handleValidation);` without the parens after `handleValidation`.

Comment: What does `getAllRequiredCtrls()` do?  And, why are you using `eval()` which is known to be slow?  Also, you are using both `objCtrls` and `ObjCtrls`.  Those are two different variables.